# What's the best English word which describes a relationship that is antagonistic on surface but friendly or comrade-like in essence?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word or phrase which describes the opposite of frenemy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivalry

Comment: Why are people voting to close this. The OP is asking for an antonym to 'frenemy'. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Well there's all [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) but the short version is, the question is considered vague unless OP provides some sort of example sentence showing how the word will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm British and I'm not sure we have a word for this. However the Americans do:

**Joshing partner**

Here's a quote from *Inside Reagan's Navy: The Pentagon Journals*
By Chase Untermeyer

[image]
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A5BKBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=joshing+%22partner%22&source=bl&ots=DizoC94ZYr&sig=NnpS5ROdRLbj9GHrjZdPvL1mBmo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMtamZle3fAhVMRBUIHetZBGsQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=joshing%20%22partner%22&f=false

> josh verb
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to engage in banter : JOKE
>
> transitive verb
>
> : to tease good-naturedly : KID
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/josh